# Can the Youtube Developer Key be used to get video keywords?

Tags: php, zend-framework, tags, youtube-api, keyword

I am using **ZendGdata 1.12.0** with PHP since Youtube decided to change the keywords/tags for videos to private.
Using a developer key would work best since I'm fetching videos from the same account and a user login wouldn't work for it.

My problem is that the ***Tags/Keywords*** are always an empty array from the Youtube API even though the video DOES have them.

My sample code can be found at https://gist.github.com/3816646 .  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a request authorized as the owner of the video if you want to get the keywords in the response. It's not enough to just use a developer key.

There are instructions for handling Authentication using the methods built-in to the PHP client library at https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Authentication

Alternatively, you could use an external OAuth 2 library, which is a more forward-compatible solution.

Comment: The problem I'm having with that is the application authorization redirect.  Viewers of the website shouldn't see that part, yet unless it's authorized, they will be asked to authorize something they don't have access to authorize.

Comment: You should handle the authorization server-side, then. The OAuth 2 for Installed Applications flow is one option: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp